# Как получить позицию последнего объекта с включенным isKinematic?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть множество объектов с именами "TileLeft", "TileTop" нужно получить позицию и имя последнего которой с включенной isKinematic.

Comment: Последнего в списке? Или тот, у которого isKinematic был включен последним?

Comment: у которого будет включен isKinematic первым, но из конца списка нужно перебирать

Comment: давайте лучше по порядку. У вас есть лист со ссылками на объекты. Эти объекты содержат на себе Rigidbody . Вам требуется получить из этого списка, проходя из конца в начало последний объект, у которого .isKinematic = true?

Comment: да, все верно написали

Comment: домой приду - напишу алгоритм)

Comment: хорошо, заранее спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack<GameObject> _stack; 

void GameObject GetLastKinematic() 
{ 
    GameObject cashObj;
    var array = _stack.ToArray();
    int count = array.Length; 
    for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    { 
        var obj = array[i];
        if (obj.activeSelf)
        {
             cashObj = obj;
        }
    } 

    return cashObj;
}
```

Т.е. мы объявляем ссылочную переменную на *GameObject*, а потом начинаем перебирать список с конца. Каждый раз, когда мы находим *isKinematic* объект - мы назначаем его в переменную и в итоге, после окончания обхода у нас останется ссылка последний из объектов, у которого стоит этот флаг.

Однако, не совсем понимаю в чем смысл обхода с конца? Ведь при обходе с начала первый же встреченный *isKinematic* объект и будет последним при обходе с конца. По сути, при проходе с конца нам нужно проверить каждый объект при каждой проверке, а при проходе с начала есть вероятность очень сильно сократить количество проверок.

А если вас устроит поиск с начала и ничего кроме получения объекта больше делать не нужно, то можно и вообще использовать Предикат и сократить код до одной строки.

```
using System.Linq;

Stack<GameObject> _stack; 

void GameObject GetLastKinematic() 
{ 
    var list = Stack.ToList();
    return _list.Find(obj => obj .activeSelf);
}
```

В этом случае произойдет поиск по листу первого же экземпляра класса, который удовлетворяет условиям в скобаках. Но для превращения стэка в лист потребуется использовать Linq.

[Документация Predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Документация List.Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Сори, забыл уточнить, у меня два Stack 'а "LeftTiles" и "TopTiles" у меня есть код которой переименовывает например из "TileTop (Clone)" в "TileTop" и каким-то образом стек получается обернутой. Потому нужно перебирать снизу. Хочу реализовать телепортацию на плитку которая ещё не упала, те которые падаю они отключаются.

Comment: ещё раз извиняюсь, нужно проверять не `IsKinematic` а на активной ли объект

Comment: @Kill Noise, а зачем вам именно стек там? Почему нельзя использовать обычный лист? А переименование на процесс никак не влияет. Код исправил с IsKinematic на активен ли объект

Comment: @Kill Noise, поправил под работу со стеком. Но, опять же, можно пройти и с начала по массиву.

Comment: Если пойти сначала конечной результат будет другой?

Comment: Между стеком и листом есть разница?

Comment: @Kill Noise, если пойти по массиву сначала, то нам нужен будет не последний встреченный, а первый. Как следствие, нам не придётся каждый раз проверять целиком весь массив. Да, между стеком и листом есть разница, можете загуглить и узнать какая)